# python non linear ODE with 2 variables

Tags: python, matlab, ode, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to solve the [Brusselator model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brusselator), a non-linear ODE, using python. I used to do this with MATLAB but now am building an application with python as a backend. That's why I want to switch ti python.

`dx/dt = A + (x^2)(y) - Bx - x`

`dy/dt = Bx - (x^2)(y)`

I have checked stackoverflow and most of examples I found are simple non-linear ODE with a single variable that can be converted into a system of linear equation. [- Sorry for my notation. I don't know how to add latex in stackoverflow]

Comment: A system is a system, if it was a scalar higher order equation or not. Only the ODE function differs in how the return vector is constructed, but that happens for every different problem. Everything else remains the same.

Comment: And if you did it in matlab, you can do it in python the same way with minimal changes. The interface for `scipy.integrate.odeint` is, if not the same, based on similar principles.

Comment: *most of examples I found are simple non-linear ODE with a single variable that can be converted into a system of linear equation* – Those were probably higher-order differential equations. You have an ordinary differential equation to begin with, but it’s already a system. There is nothing to do here from the mathematical point of view. So, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. Nevertheless, I managed to formulate your question in the code below.

There, I implemented your two differential equations in a single function, that I later integrate through ODEINT module from scypy.

I hope this answer your problem.

Sincerely yours,

```
import scipy.integrate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Integrate(y, t, B, A):
    X, Y = y

    dX_dt = A + (X**2)*(Y) - B*X - X

    dY_dt = B*X - (X**2)*(Y)



    return [dX_dt, dY_dt]

A0 = 0.9
B0 = 0.6
X0 = 0.1
Y0 = 0.0
B0 = 0.35


t = np.linspace(0,100, 10000)


solution = scipy.integrate.odeint(Integrate, y0=[X0, Y0], t=t, args=(A0, B0) )

plt.plot(t, solution[:,1], label='solution')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
```