# Solve a nonlinear ODE system for the Frenet frame

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I have checked [python non linear ODE with 2 variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177803/python-non-linear-ode-with-2-variables) , which is not my case. Maybe my case is not called as `nonlinear ODE`, correct me please.

The question is`Frenet Frame` actually, in which there are 3 vectors T(s), N(s) and B(s); the parameter s>=0. And there are 2 scalar with known math formula expression t(s) and k(s). I have the initial value T(0), N(0) and B(0).

```
diff(T(s), s) =             k(s)*N(s)
diff(N(s), s) = -k(s)*T(s)            + t(s)*B(s)
diff(B(s), s) =            -t(s)*N(s)
```

Then how can I get T(s), N(s) and B(s) numerically or symbolically?

I have checked `scipy.integrate.ode` but I don't know how to pass k(s)*N(s) into its first parameter at all

```
def model (z, tspan):
   T = z[0]
   N = z[1]
   B = z[2]

   dTds =            k(s) * N           # how to express function k(s)?      
   dNds = -k(s) * T          + t(s) * B
   dBds =           -t(s)* N

   return [dTds, dNds, dBds]


z = scipy.integrate.ode(model, [T0, N0, B0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code using [`solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) interface from Scipy (instead of `odeint`) to obtain a numerical solution:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# Define the parameters as regular Python function:
def k(s):
    return 1

def t(s):
    return 0

# The equations: dz/dt = model(s, z):
def model(s, z):
    T = z[:3]   # z is a (9, ) shaped array, the concatenation of T, N and B 
    N = z[3:6]
    B = z[6:]

    dTds =            k(s) * N  
    dNds = -k(s) * T          + t(s) * B
    dBds =           -t(s)* N

    return np.hstack([dTds, dNds, dBds])


T0, N0, B0 = [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1] 

z0 = np.hstack([T0, N0, B0])

s_span = (0, 6) # start and final "time"
t_eval = np.linspace(*s_span, 100)  # define the number of point wanted in-between,
                                    # It is not necessary as the solver automatically
                                    # define the number of points.
                                    # It is used here to obtain a relatively correct 
                                    # integration of the coordinates, see the graph

# Solve:
sol = solve_ivp(model, s_span, z0, t_eval=t_eval, method='RK45')
print(sol.message)
# >> The solver successfully reached the end of the integration interval.

# Unpack the solution:
T, N, B = np.split(sol.y, 3)  # another way to unpack the z array
s = sol.t

# Bonus: integration of the normal vector in order to get the coordinates
#        to plot the curve  (there is certainly better way to do this)
coords = cumtrapz(T, x=s)

plt.plot(coords[0, :], coords[1, :]);
plt.axis('equal'); plt.xlabel('x'); plt.xlabel('y');
```

T, N and B are vectors. Therefore, there are 9 equations to solve: `z` is a (9,) array.

For constant curvature and no torsion, the result is a circle:

[image: a circle]

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your example. And I thought it again, found that since there is formula for dZ where Z is matrix(T, N, B), we can calculate `Z[i] = Z[i-1] + dZ[i-1]*deltaS` according to the concept of derivative. Then I code and find this idea can solve the circle example. So

1. is `Z[i] = Z[i-1] + dZ[i-1]*deltaS` suitable for other ODE? will it fail in some situation, or does scipy.integrate.solve_ivp/scipy.integrate.ode supply advantage over the direct usage of `Z[i] = Z[i-1] + dZ[i-1]*deltaS`?
2. in my code, I have to normalize Z[i] because ||Z[i]|| is not always 1. Why does it happen? A float numerical calculation error?

my answer to my question, at least it works for the circle

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# Define the parameters as regular Python function:
def k(s):
    return 1

def t(s):
    return 0

def dZ(s, Z):
    return np.array(
        [k(s) * Z[1], -k(s) * Z[0] + t(s) * Z[2], -t(s)* Z[1]]
    )

T0, N0, B0 = np.array([1, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 1, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 1])

deltaS = 0.1    # step to calculate dZ/ds
num = int(2*np.pi*1/deltaS) + 1 # how many points on the curve we have to calculate

T = np.zeros([num, ], dtype=object)
N = np.zeros([num, ], dtype=object)
B = np.zeros([num, ], dtype=object)

T[0] = T0
N[0] = N0
B[0] = B0

for i in range(num-1):
    temp_dZ = dZ(i*deltaS, np.array([T[i], N[i], B[i]]))
    T[i+1] = T[i] + temp_dZ[0]*deltaS
    T[i+1] = T[i+1]/np.linalg.norm(T[i+1])  # have to do this

    N[i+1] = N[i] + temp_dZ[1]*deltaS
    N[i+1] = N[i+1]/np.linalg.norm(N[i+1])

    B[i+1] = B[i] + temp_dZ[2]*deltaS
    B[i+1] = B[i+1]/np.linalg.norm(B[i+1])


coords = cumtrapz(
    [
        [i[0] for i in T], [i[1] for i in T], [i[2] for i in T]
    ]
    , x=np.arange(num)*deltaS
)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(coords[0, :], coords[1, :]);
plt.axis('equal'); plt.xlabel('x'); plt.xlabel('y');

plt.show()
```

Comment: that's the Euler method, it works! but usually not used because not stable and not efficient, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations  or  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-086-mathematical-methods-for-engineers-ii-spring-2006/video-lectures/lecture-1-difference-methods-for-ordinary-differential-equations/. One of the methods used by `solve_ivp` is [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the equation I listed in the first post does not work for my curve. So I read `Gray A., Abbena E., Salamon S-Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica. 2006` and found that for arbitrary curve, Frenet equation should be written as

```
diff(T(s), s) = ||r'||*           k(s)*N(s)
diff(N(s), s) = ||r'||*(-k(s)*T(s)            + t(s)*B(s))
diff(B(s), s) = ||r'||*          -t(s)*N(s)
```

where `||r'||`(or `||r'(s)||`) is `diff([x(s), y(s), z(s)], s).norm()`

now the problem has changed to be some different from that in the first  post, because there is no r'(s) function or discrete data array. **So I think this is suitable for a new reply other than comment.**

I met 2 questions while trying to solve the new equation:

1. how can we program with r'(s) if scipy's solve_ivp is used?
2. I try to modify my `gaussian solution`, but the result is totally wrong.

thanks again

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# Define the parameters as regular Python function:
def k(s):
    return 1

def t(s):
    return 0

def dZ(s, Z, r_norm):
    return np.array([
        r_norm * k(s) * Z[1],
        r_norm*(-k(s) * Z[0] + t(s) * Z[2]),
        r_norm*(-t(s)* Z[1])
    ])

T0, N0, B0 = np.array([1, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 1, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 1])

deltaS = 0.1    # step to calculate dZ/ds
num = int(2*np.pi*1/deltaS) + 1 # how many points on the curve we have to calculate

T = np.zeros([num, ], dtype=object)
N = np.zeros([num, ], dtype=object)
B = np.zeros([num, ], dtype=object)
R0 = N0

T[0] = T0
N[0] = N0
B[0] = B0

for i in range(num-1):
    r_norm = np.linalg.norm(R0)
    temp_dZ = dZ(i*deltaS, np.array([T[i], N[i], B[i]]), r_norm)
    T[i+1] = T[i] + temp_dZ[0]*deltaS
    T[i+1] = T[i+1]/np.linalg.norm(T[i+1])

    N[i+1] = N[i] + temp_dZ[1]*deltaS
    N[i+1] = N[i+1]/np.linalg.norm(N[i+1])

    B[i+1] = B[i] + temp_dZ[2]*deltaS
    B[i+1] = B[i+1]/np.linalg.norm(B[i+1])

    R0 = R0 + T[i]*deltaS

coords = cumtrapz(
    [
        [i[0] for i in T], [i[1] for i in T], [i[2] for i in T]
    ]
    , x=np.arange(num)*deltaS
)


plt.figure()
plt.plot(coords[0, :], coords[1, :]);
plt.axis('equal'); plt.xlabel('x'); plt.xlabel('y');

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you include the definition of the curve you want to compute? Is `||r'||` a given parameter similar `k(s)` and `t(s)`?  `diff([x(s), y(s), z(s)], s)` is actually `T` the tangent vector and its norm remains 1 along the computation, I don't think there is a need to force the normalization

Comment: No, in fact, `r(s)` is what I want to get after calculation - just like you do in the circle example. All the known conditions are: `t(s)`, `k(s)`, `T0`, `N0`, `B0`, `r(0)` and `Frenet Frame equation`.In case you need the background, I am studying [`Shape sensing using multi-core fiber optic cable and parametric curve solutions` by `Jason P. Moore`]( https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/abstract.cfm?uri=oe-20-3-2967), and find that `5. Solving for shape` can't solve my curve correctly.

Comment: Then I found on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves) and in `Gray A., Abbena E., Salamon S-Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica. 2006` that the equation should be `dZ = ||r'||function(Z, k, t)`. In my first post, ||r'||==1 because the curve is so-called unit-speed curve. Thank you for your help. And sorry to make the problem some out of Math-only.

Comment: my bad, the above code is wrong, because it is `||r'(s)||` but I use `||r(s)||`. Then the problem is if it possible to calculate `||r'(s)||`